# Flask and Jinja2 url_for error - concatenating json object into url_for

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, mapbox

I am using Flask with Jinja2 and MapBox on a project which involves plotting data on a map using GeoJSON derived from model data.  Example of how this is loaded:

```
$.getJSON("{{ url_for(".geojson") }}", function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

     //do stuff

      }
    });
    markers.addLayer(geojson);

    var map = L.map('map', {maxZoom: 9, minZoom: 3}).fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
    baseLayer.addTo(map);
    markers.addTo(map);
```

An example of using this JSON data within my JS:

```
var feature = e.layer.feature;
//print item name
console.log(feature.properties.name)
//print item latitude
console.log(feature.properties.latitude)
//print item category info
console.log(feature.properties.category.name)
```

This works great. My dataset has now extended to include image urls (example `09379_580_360.jpg`), and the images themselves are hosted in a `static/images/eol` folder. I'd like to include these as an image within a DIV, of which I am setting dynamically via JS like so...

```
var commoncontent = '<div class="panel-heading"><h3>'+feature.properties.name+'</h3></div>'
$('#common').html(commoncontent)
```

However, when I attempt to concatenate my image data into jinja's url_for...

```
var commoncontent = '<div><img src="{{ url_for("static", filename="images/eol/thumbs/big/'+feature.properties.category.localimageurl.jpg+'") }}"></div>'
```

... I get this error in my console

```
 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/eol/thumbs/big/feature.properties.category.localimageurl.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

I know that `feature.properties.category.localimageurl` is correct as it prints to my console when I console.log() it. However, I have no idea why the interpreter is taking it directly as a string and not concatenating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feature` is a JavaScript object. Jinja doesn't have access to those; it runs on the server, whereas your JavaScript runs in the client. `feature` doesn't exist when your template is rendered. You will need to handle the concatenation with JavaScript.

```
var commoncontent = '<div><img src="{{ url_for("static", filename="images/eol/thumbs/big/") }}' + feature.properties.category.localimageurl.jpg + '"></div>'
```